# Can't insert into a database wordpress

Tags: php, database, mysql, forms, wp-insert-post

i did a form with html and js, and through a plugin in php, i wish i could insert the result of this form into my wordpress database. But i run into multiples problems.
One was that wordpress would told me he couldnt find one column that actually existed, and now that i removed that column, while wordpress tell me the insertion was sucessfull, my table is still empty, nothing is added into it.
Sorry my code and data are in french, if really needed i will translate it, i need help.

There is my database table :

```
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Nom VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Prenom VARCHAR(255),
Adresse VARCHAR(255),
`Code-Postale` VARCHAR(5),
Naissance DATE,
Telephone VARCHAR(10),
Mail VARCHAR(255),
`Probleme-de-sante` VARCHAR(255),
handicap ENUM('Non', 'Oui'),
RQTH ENUM('RQTH-Valides', 'RQTH-En-Attente', 'Pas-de-RQTH'),
`AucuneAide` VARCHAR(255),
`Aide-Technique` VARCHAR(255),
`Aide-Humaine` VARCHAR(255),
`Autre-aide` VARCHAR(255),
`nom_contact_urgence` VARCHAR(255),
`Prenom-Contact-Urgence` VARCHAR(255),
`Relation-Contact-Urgence` VARCHAR(255),
`Numero-Contact-Urgence` VARCHAR(10),
Classe ENUM('Premiere-Annee', 'Deuxieme-Annee', 'Troisieme-Annee', 'Senpai'),
Paiement ENUM('Paiement-Annuel', 'Paiement-Trimestre', 'Paiement-Seance'),
reglement ENUM('espece', 'virement', 'cheque'),
dateEncaissement ENUM('5', '15', '25'),
Rythme ENUM('Hebdomadaire', 'Mensuel'),
Creneaux VARCHAR(255)
```

Then this is my php code :

```
function traiter_formulaire() {

if (isset($_POST['submit_formulaire']) && isset($_POST['inscription_form'])) {
    global $wpdb;
    echo "La fonction traiter_formulaire s'execute";
    // Choisir le nom de la table en fonction du bouton radio sélectionné
    $table_name = '';

    if ($_POST['est_majeur'] == 'oui') {
echo "Il s'agit d'un majeur";
        $table_name = 'wp_inscriptions_majeurs';
$reponse = array(
'Nom' => '',
'Prenom' => '',
'Adresse' => '',
'Code-Postale' => '',
'Naissance' => '',
'Telephone' => '',
'Mail' => '',
'Probleme-de-sante' => '',
'handicap' => '',
'RQTH' => '', // Mettre à jour la valeur par défaut pour le type tinyint
'AucuneAide' => '', // Mettre à jour la valeur par défaut pour le type tinyint
'Aide-Technique' => '', // Mettre à jour la valeur par défaut pour le type tinyint
'Aide-Humaine' => '', // Mettre à jour la valeur par défaut pour le type tinyint
'Autre-aide' => '', // Mettre à jour la valeur par défaut pour le type tinyint
'nom_contact_urgence' => '',
'Prenom-Contact-Urgence' => '',
'Relation-Contact-Urgence' => '',
'Numero-Contact-Urgence' => '',
'Paiement' => '',
'reglement' => '',
'dateEncaissement' => '',
'Creneaux' => '',
);


    } else {
//echo "Il s'agit d'un mineur";
        $table_name = 'wp_inscriptions_mineurs';
    }
    
    // Retirer les éléments non liés aux réponses
    unset($_POST['submit_formulaire']);
    unset($_POST['inscription_form']);
    unset($_POST['est_majeur']);
    
   
    // Parcourir le tableau $_POST et nettoyer chaque valeur
     foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

if (!empty($value)) {
//echo "je travaille sur" . sanitize_text_field($value) . "\n";
    $reponse[$key] = sanitize_text_field($value);
}

}

   echo "<pre>";
echo "le nom de la table est :" . $table_name;
print_r($reponse);
echo "</pre>";

print_r($_POST);


    // Créer un tableau vide pour stocker les réponses nettoyées
    $reponse = array();
    
    // Parcourir le tableau $_POST et nettoyer chaque valeur
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) {
            $reponse[$key] = sanitize_text_field($value);
        }
    }

    // Insérer les données en utilisant $wpdb->insert
    $result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $reponse);


// Vérifier le résultat
if ($result === false) {
  echo "Erreur lors de l'insertion des données : " . $wpdb->last_error;
} else {
    echo "L'insertion des données a réussi";
}
print_r($wpdb->queries);


$result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data);

}
}
?>
```

And there is the different result of the request you see :

**le nom de la table est :wp_inscriptions_majeurs** => This line confirm that the name of the table is correct.

```
Array
(
    [Nom] => The first name i did type
    [Prenom] => The last name i did type
    [Adresse] => 21
    [Code-Postale] => 31300
    [Naissance] => 2000-12-12
    [Telephone] => The number i did type
    [Mail] => the mail i did type
    [Probleme-de-sante] => 
    [handicap] => Non
    [RQTH] => 
    [AucuneAide] => 
    [Aide-Technique] => 
    [Aide-Humaine] => 
    [Autre-aide] => 
    [nom_contact_urgence] => 
    [Prenom-Contact-Urgence] => 
    [Relation-Contact-Urgence] => 
    [Numero-Contact-Urgence] => 
    [Paiement] => 
    [reglement] => 
    [dateEncaissement] => 
    [Creneaux] => 
)
```

As you can see, some of the column are empty. It's normal, i removed them just to see if it would work as i explained at the top.

```
Array ( [Nom] => FirstName [Prenom] => LastName [Adresse] => 21 [Code-Postale] => 31300 [Naissance] => 2000-12-12 [Telephone] => Number [Mail] => mail [Probleme-de-sante] => [handicap] => Non [Autre-aide] => [selectHeureIlluAdulteHebdo] => [selectHeureJaponaisAdulteHebdoSenpai] => [spe1SelectHeureMangaAdulteHebdo] => [spe1SelectHeureDessinAdulteHebdo] => [spe2SelectHeureMangaAdulteHebdo] => [spe2SelectHeureIlluAdulteHebdo] => [selectHeureMangaAdoMensuelUn] => [spe3SelectHeureMangaAdoHebdo] => [spe3SelectHeureDessinAdoHebdo] => )
```

```
INSERT INTO `wp_inscriptions_majeurs` (`Nom`, `Prenom`, `Adresse`, `Code-Postale`, `Naissance`, `Telephone`, `Mail`, `handicap`) VALUES ('LastName', 'FirstName', '21', '31300', '2000-12-12', 'phone', 'mail', 'Non')
```

Those are the column that should receive an answer since i did put something in the form as reply to it.

And then ofc :
**L'insertion des données a réussi** => Tell me that the insert was sucessfull.
So at this point, i have no idea of what is wrong and why i can't see anything in the data. Worst thing is, from my print_r($wpdb->queries), i can see multiple submissions i did to the form that are right. So i don't know how it is possible. I see 25 different submissions that was done on different day. How can it keep so much of the informations if there are not even kept anywhere in the database ? For example :

```
    [16] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 17
            [Nom] => Test
            [Prenom] => Test
            [Adresse] => Test
            [Code-Postale] => Test
            [Naissance] => 2000-01-01
            [Telephone] => Test
            [Mail] => test@test.com
            [Probleme-de-sante] => 
            [handicap] => Test
            [RQTH] => 
            [Autre-aide] => 
        )
```

This one was done like 4 days ago...
I need your help please.
Thanks a lot.